# Saving PyFPDF outputs to a relative path

Tags: python

Is there any options to the below code to save the file in the relative path? I tried changing the below code but I am getting an error.

Before:

```
pdf.output("D:\\Python Projects\\project\\output\\" + str(emp_id) + ".pdf")
```

After:

```
pdf.output("\\project\\output\\" + str(emp_id) + ".pdf")
```

Comment: try `rel_path = "D:\\Python Projects"` and that keep track of it. Use `os.path.join` to join path, i.e. `import os; pdf.output(os.path.join(rel_path, 'project', 'output', f'{emp_id}.pdf'))`

Comment: otherwise run python from `rel_path` and use `.`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Anyhow, I want the output dir to be dynamic.

Comment: What kind of error you get? Add the full traceback

Comment: if you try the method mentioned by cards, you can make the relative path dynamic. Have you tried the method?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet because I am going to use that variable to another functions in my program but I dont want to return it. For now I might keep it like this, but I really appreciate your inputs.